# Selenium webdriver not working. Unable to decipher error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am just starting to learn selenium automation, and I am stuck at a part where even though I follow tutorials to the point, it does not work

**--My code--
**

```
package newAttemptPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class NewTryClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\919so\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Selenium\\selenium-java-4.15.0\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");   
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        driver.close();
        
        
    }

}
```

**What the error says
**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at anotherTry/tryPackage.TryClass.main(TryClass.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 4 more
```

**I have all the JAR files from the lastest stable version of selenium.
I have the lastest stable version of the chrome webdriver
and I am using java 8 on eclipse **

[image: A screenshot of some of the jar files]

Answer (score 0):

I have to use Java 1.8 version
You can see on the JRE System libaray it says "[JavaSE-17]"
it should say "[JavaSE-1.8]"